# Mortarboard badge awarded unjustly?

Tags: bug, badges, daily-reputation-badges

My [main account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343266/jimmy-keen) at Stackoverflow has just been awarded `Mortarboard` badge (it happened as I received couple of upvotes for my recent answer). Problem is, I was nowehere near 200 reputation today, not even in past 24 hours (my initial thought why would that happen). I also checked my reputation history to see if there's a +200 change anywhere, but I can't see it. Is there a bug or am I missing something obvious in the way it works?

**Edit:** I went though my reputation page and there's no meaningful change coming from removed posts. Majority of changes is less than 10 rep, and those differences never occured during the days where they could cause 200+ boost. Badge is still here, which makes me think it is a bug indeed.

Comment: Strange - highest I can see is 160 in a day.

Comment: @Oded it may be the case of rollback of repo due to false upvotes or removal of post or even 200 repo crossing rollback.

Comment: @Jason_vorhees - True, looks like a likely explanation. If no such removal occurred, however, then this is a bug.

Answer (score 15):

We have *no* idea how this happened, I cannot give you an explanation.  The badge ran, you got the badge...I can't explain why.  It's a very straight-forward query that somehow got your user Id...but I can't replicate the confluence of events that triggered such a thing.

I cleaned up the data (cache has to expire yet), but sorry...after hours and hours of looking for any possible explanation, nothing comes remotely close.  For the record, ***yes*** this  does bug the hell out of me, it's the first bug we've had that I can't explain.

If somehow we trip upon the answer down the road, I'll be sure to post the explanation here.

Comment: Should I accept your answer Nick or leave the question open until you guys *"trip upon the answer"*? Not really sure how you handle this stuff on meta. Thanks for clearing the badge too.

Comment: @jimmy_keen - IMO leave this "open", that's pretty accurate.

Comment: *The [badge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch) ran* -- that could have caused it? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan - semantics there may be confusing...every badge is a self-contained class that runs itself pretty much (DRY coded where possible, of course)...trust me when I say the old way was ummmm "more fun"?

Comment: [Oops it did it again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132666/why-did-i-just-earn-mortarboard) maybe Bounty is involved somehow? Can you check for such a thing?

Comment: Looks like the bug is still active; see:  http://stackoverflow.com/users/1501794/rahul-tripathi?tab=badges

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - he earned the badge in the past, there are some now-deleted posts involved on a previous day.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked the "show removed posts" checkbox in your reputation tab? Maybe you crossed the 200 rep bar, so you got the badge, but due to the faulty votes removal process you lost it again.

Maybe some of your upvoted posts were removed, but contributed to the badge before you lost the rep. Badges are never rescinded.

So check "show removed posts" and see if you can find a hint.

Comment: Checked again with *show removed posts* checked - highest is still 160. My /reputation page also list 0 days with 200 reputation cap reached.

Comment: @jimmy_keen  sometimes repotation down because of falsely upvote doesnot show that quickly, check sometime after. And don't just check the total repo of every day, check the detailed repo for every day without the minus of repo for that day and do a total of it.

Comment: @lunboks thax for making it more readable and for making necesarry correction.

Comment: Thanks for tip. I did initially check and highest change caused by *removal* was at -10 reputation (none of the changes I noticed could cause fluctuations up to 200 rep, they did mostly happen on little reputation days, like 10-30). I will check again in couple of hours.

Comment: @jimmy_keen if checking after some time also not helping to know the answer then it must be a bug, so report it to SE team.

Comment: @Jason_vorhees: no need to contact the SE team directly, this is the right place to report bugs.