# Why did I just earn mortarboard?

Tags: bug, badges, daily-reputation-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mortarboard badge awarded unjustly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128934/mortarboard-badge-awarded-unjustly)

Today, I hit 200 rep for the month. At the same time, I earned the mortarboard badge. I haven't had any days with over 75 rep. So why did I get the mortarboard badge?

Comment: OP's SO profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/259014/jeffrey-blake?tab=reputation&sort=graph

Comment: Hey, if you don't want it, can I have it? ;P

Comment: Because you are __killer__ programming.  You are 1337, the bomb. You can haz send teh codez. You are Jon Skeet.  You are Chuck Norris. You are deadly.

Comment: *I haven't had any days with over 75 rep.* Not even if you include deleted posts?

Comment: Dennis: That might bump it over 75, but not over 100.

Comment: Did you check? All you have to do is toggle `show removed posts` on your reputation page. (Insisting since I can't think of anything else.)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nWx78.jpg

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, I checked. Nothing this year over 100 points in a day (let alone 200), regardless of whether removed posts are included or not.

Comment: Have you by any chance answered a Bounty question recently? Maybe you were awarded the bounty then somehow it got revoked.

Comment: Also, when visiting your [reputation report page](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) what you see in the bottom for "earned at least 200 reputation on [X] days" as the X?

Comment: "earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days". I have not answered a bounty question recently (i.e. Not in 2012)